# Secure storage of tennant/client id on application web server

Tags: php, azure, security

Ive recently started looking into authenticating with azure active directory using client credentials grant with public/private certificates as detailed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

Im running an external PHP/LEMP server outside of the azure hosting platform etc etc.

I've managed to get the connection to azure ad working successfully as seen below:

[image]

The question is more how we do the credential storage so i can actually do the authorisation. The ironic thing is, i need to store these credentials so i can access ones stored securely within the key vault! So im just wondering does anyone have any recommendations for storing of the:

- Tennant ID
- Client ID
- Scope Uri (i guess i should include this to, as it's an id/guid as such)

Is it safe to store these values as plain text within a sites database?
Would you recommend environment variables? Just wondering what peoples approach is to this.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you store these variables in Key Vault, that's the most secure option. However, then obviously you need keys to access Key Vault.

If you were running your web app in Azure then this would be easy. You can use managed identity to give your web app an identity, and grant this access to KV, done. As your running outside of Azure, the next best method would be to generate a service principal that authenticates with a certificate, grant this service principal access to key vault, then store the private key on your web server and use this to auth. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-authenticate-service-principal-powershell) for details on creating a service principal.